# Flask-mail: How to handle multiple email requests at once

Tags: flask, flask-mail

So I wrote a dedicated flask app for handling emails for my application and deployed it on heroku. In which I have set up a route to send emails:

```
@app.route('/send', methods=['POST'])
def send_now():
    with app.app_context():
      values = request.get_json()
      email = values['email']
      code = values['code']
      secret_2 = str(values['secret'])
      mail = Mail(app)
      msg = Message("Password Recovery",sender="no*****@gmail.com",recipients=[email])
      msg.html = "<h1>Your Recovery Code is: </h1><p>"+str(code)+"</p>"
      if secret == secret_2:
        mail.send(msg)
        response = {'message': 'EmailSent'}
        return jsonify(response), 201
```

It works fine for a single user at a time, however when multiple users send a POST request, the client user needs to wait till the POST returns a 201. Thus the wait period keeps increasing (it may not even send). So how do I handle this so accommodate multiple simultaneous users. Threads? Buffer? I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send mail via Asynchronous thread calls in Python. Have a look at this code sample and implement in your code.

```
from threading import Thread
from app import app

def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[app, msg])
    thr.start()
```

This will allow to send the mail in background.